# Aframe how to reset default scale after loading the GLTF model

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am trying to make an app which adds models from Google poly in GLTF format.

I had the issue of some models being extremely large when added on the scene which I solved by computing their size with bounding box max and min values and setting the scale amount.

Now after adding the objects to the scene when I open the inspector and drag to scale objects, even with a small amount of drag the objects becomes very large.

If there is any way to reset the scale value of loaded objects so that default value can be the value which I computed and this can also solve the drag to scale issue.

**Note:** The computed scale factor for some elements goes to 0.00001 for x, y, z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the three.js API within A-Frame components to compute a bounding box of the model, then scale it down to the size you prefer. Example:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('autoscale', {
  schema: {type: 'number', default: 1},
  init: function () {
    this.scale();
    this.el.addEventListener('object3dset', () => this.scale());
  },
  scale: function () {
    const el = this.el;
    const span = this.data;
    const mesh = el.getObject3D('mesh');

    if (!mesh) return;

    // Compute bounds.
    const bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);

    // Normalize scale.
    const scale = span / bbox.getSize().length();
    mesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);

    // Recenter.
    const offset = bbox.getCenter().multiplyScalar(scale);
    mesh.position.sub(offset);
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<a-entity autoscale="2" gltf-model="stereo.gltf"></a-entity>
```

The code above will fit your model to a ~2m box, and re-center it. For more information see [THREE.Object3D documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D).

three.js r89, A-Frame 0.8.0.

Comment: I think the problem is after the rescale, where he tries to change the scale by hitting "r" in the inspector, and the dimensions go crazy. if You need to rescale it by 0.00001 and the inspector goes from 10 to -10, it makes it impossible to adjust. Is it possible to change the size of the object without rescaling ?

Comment: Hm, the A-Frame inspector UI may not be able to deal with large values like this... the approach above will still work, though. Using `setAttribute('scale', ...)` would also be fine.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy thanks for writing a component. 

Will see if I can use it somehow.

Comment: It works like a charm.

So to initialize a scale I guess you need to access that object3dset event and resize the mesh scale in order to set the default size.

That recenter thing is just cherry on top for this answer.

Thanks a lot @DonMcCurdy

Comment: @mr.339 this whole answer is dependent on the assumption that you're loading glTF models into an application built in [A-Frame](https://aframe.io/). If that's not the case, you'll probably want to open a new question with details about your issue.