# Aframe: glTF sizing and re-centering of multiple mesh model

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am importing a glTF model which has two meshes using

```
<a-entity gltf='#sofa'>
```

assume sofa is an `asset-item` pointing to the resource. I am trying to write a component that will resize the model and re-center if required. I have been able to successfully do it using

```
  this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", function(e) {
  var model = e.detail.model;
  model.traverse(function(o) {
    if (o instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        o.geometry.center();
        o.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        var bBox = o.geometry.boundingBox;
        d = bBox.max.z - bBox.min.z;
        w = bBox.max.x - bBox.min.x;
        h = bBox.max.y - bBox.min.y;
        switch(axis) {
          case 'x':
          scale = sizeto / w;
          break;
          case 'y':
          scale = sizeto / h;
          break;
          case 'z':
          scale = sizeto / d;
          break;
          default:
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    el.setAttribute('scale', scale + ' ' + scale + ' ' + scale);
  });
```

The properties of the component include specifying the `axis` viz x, y or z that is being resized and the `sizeto` value. This works well for single mesh models.

For multiple mesh models I have even tried to specify the main mesh (assuming one of them is important) and given the `axis` and `sizeto` and applied it to the whole element. That too works.

The case that I have not been able to handle is when I want the whole model to be re-centered or the origin changed say to the centre of the resulting model or having an origin of `0 0 0`.

Is there any way other than `geometry.center()` that can be used to re-center the whole model? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aframe how to reset default scale after loading the GLTF model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379435/aframe-how-to-reset-default-scale-after-loading-the-gltf-model)

Comment: Thanks @DonMcCurdy. Missed finding that. Thanks